# How to get a GenericList sorted by a property

Tags: c#, linq, generics, compact-framework

I need to sort a list based on a property (IsValid = true) with all true items on top and the rest below it.Since I'm using compact framework, I can't use OrderBy. Can anyone post me LINQ query to get the list ?

```
 List<Record> records = GetRecords();
```

Comment: `"I'm using compact framework, I can't use OrderBy"`, Why? `OrderBy` in `Linq` works fine on `CompactFramework`

Comment: I find it hard to believe that CF supports Linq, but not OrderBy.

Comment: Can you use OrderBy? I don't have access to it at all.

Comment: `var sorted = records.Where(t=>t.IsValid).Concat(records.Where(t=>!t.IsValid));`

Comment: But you should be able to `OrderBy` - are you `using System.Linq`?

Comment: [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.90).aspx) states that `OrderBy` is supported in the Compact Framework version 3.5 and above.

Comment: I missed the namespace.Now can you send me the simpler LINQ query?

Comment: `records.OrderBy(t=>!t.IsValid)` should do it. If it's backwards, remove the `!`

Comment: I also need the rest to sort by Id desc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

records.OrderBy(rec => !rec.IsValid).OrderByDescending(re => re.Id);